# Configure specific modules to be built as forwarding require

Tags: webpack, webpack-2

I am developing a server side node.js application and am producing a bundle using webpack 2 with the following configuration:

```
{
  entry: [
    './api/server.js'
  ],
  target: 'node',
  devtool: 'source-map',
  context: path.resolve(__dirname, '..'),
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'build', 'server'),
    filename: 'server.js'
  },

  resolve: {
    modules: ['node_modules'],
    extensions: ['.js']
  },

  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: [
            ['es2015', { modules: false }],
            'stage-0'
          ],
          plugins: [
            'transform-object-rest-spread',
            'babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy',
            'transform-class-properties'
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.json$/,
        loader: 'json-loader'
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

One of my depedencies is the node-argon2 library and I import this library in `server.js`. The resulting bundle file produced by webpack has included the argon2 code (for example):

```
,
/* 62 */
/* unknown exports provided */
/* all exports used */
/*!*MYPROJECT/~/argon2/index.js ***!!*\
/***/ function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {

"use strict";
eval("'use strict'\nconst crypto....
```

When this is the case I get the following error:

```
(node:23259) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): TypeError: Path must be a string. Received undefined
(node:23259) DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I reproduce the above error with a minimal `server.js` that only imports the argon2 module. Thinking this may have to do with the fact that the argon2 library invokes native code I marked the module external and replaced its entry in the webpack built file to be:

```
/***/ },
/* 163 */
/* unknown exports provided */
/* all exports used */
/*!*************************!*\
  !*** external "argon2" ***!
  \*************************/
/***/ function(module, exports) {

eval("module.exports = require(\"argon2\");");
```

This now works without any errors. Clearly marking this external is not correct (and wouldn't work at all without the above modification). I'm looking to configure the argon2 module to result in a entry similar to the above. I have noticed that this matches the way `string_decoder`, `tty`, `zlip` and some other modules are defined in the bundle:

```
/***/ },
/* 164 */
/* unknown exports provided */
/* all exports used */
/*!*********************************!*\
  !*** external "string_decoder" ***!
  \*********************************/
/***/ function(module, exports) {

eval("module.exports = require(\"string_decoder\");...")

/***/ },
/* 165 */
/* unknown exports provided */
/* all exports used */
/*!**********************!*\
  !*** external "tty" ***!
  \**********************/
/***/ function(module, exports) {

eval("module.exports = require(\"tty\");
```